# I can't consume the resource. I'm Using Java EE 7/JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have this service:

```
@Stateless
@Path(value = "tasks")
public class TasksFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Tasks> {
```

I can access the app through:

```
localhost:8080/todo
```

However, this gives me a 404:

```
localhost:8080/todo/tasks
```

I do have this method in the tasks service:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Tasks> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

I already tried to access it through curl like this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -v http://localhost:8080/todo/tasks
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: ooh, delicious, resources! (sorry I couldn't resist `:P`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct URL was:

```
http://localhost:8080/todo/webresources/tasks
```

There's also an ApplicationConfig.java file that states:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
```